# Some questions about $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2z)^{-n^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been given this exercise:

Show that $F(z) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2z)^{-n^2}$ is holomorphic in $\Omega :=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| > 1/2\}$ and also to infinity.

Then, for every non negative integer k, evaluate $$\int_{C_{1}(0)} z^k F(z)\ dz$$

I'm really in trouble and I don't know where to begin. Every hint or more detailed help would be kindly appreciated.

---

**Edit:**

Let's define $f_n(z) := (2z)^{-n^2}$. Then $F(z) = \sum_n f(z)$ is holomphic in $\Omega$ if:

-$f_n(z)$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$

-the sum converges uniformly on every compact subset of $\Omega$

$\\$

Now, $f(z)$ have one singularity in $z=0 \notin \Omega$, so they are holomorphic.

Thanks to Weierstrass' theorem if exists $M_n \ge 0$ s.t. for all $z \in \Omega$ it holds $|f_n(z)|\le M_n$ and $\sum_n M_n < \infty$, then $\sum_n f(z)$ converges uniformly in $\Omega$

I can see that for all $|z| > 1/2$ we have $$(|2z|)^{n^2} = 2^{n^2} |z|^{n^2} > 2^{n^2} 2^{-n^2} = 1$$

$$\frac{1}{(|2z|)^{n^2}} < 1$$

But taking $M_n = 1$ their sum does not converge.. Now here I get stucked.

Comment: Set $w=1/2z$, then you have to prove $\sum_n w^{n^2}$ is holomorphic on the unit disc. I'd use Weierstrass's M-test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, let $G(z)=F(\frac1z)$. Proving the fact that $F$ is holomorphic in $|z|>\frac12$ is equivalent to proving that $G$ is holomorfic in $|z|<2$ (we'll call this region $\Gamma$).

To prove it, consider $\Gamma_k:=|z|\le k<2$. Then,  $\forall z\in \Gamma_k$,

$$
|z|\le k\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)^{n^2}<\infty\\
G(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac z2\right)^{n^2}\\$$

By Weierstrass M test, the series converges uniformly on all of the $\Gamma_k$. Since every compact subset of $\Gamma$ is contained in at least one of the $\Gamma_k$, we have proved the uniform convergence on every compact subset of $\Gamma$ of $G_n$, which are analytic (since they are polynomials), and thus we have proved that $G$ is analytic in $\Gamma$.

To compute the integral, let us use the substitution $u=\frac{1}{z}; -\frac{du}{u^2}=dz;$

$$\oint_{C_1(0)}z^kF(z)dz=\oint_{C_1(0)}\frac{1}{u^{k+2}}G(u)du=\\
=\oint_{C_1(0)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{{u}^{n^2-k-2}}{2^{n^2}}du=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n^2}}\oint_{C_1(0)}u^{n^2-k-2}du$$

(we used the fact that the transformation $z=\frac{1}{u}$ changes the orientation of the unit circle and that, since $C_1(0)\in \Gamma_{1}$, the convergence of the series is uniform, so we can exchange the integral and the sum)

Remembering that $\oint z^adz=2\pi i\cdot \delta^a_{-1}$, the result is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n^2}}\oint_{C_1(0)}u^{n^2-k-2}du=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2\pi i}{2^{n^2}}\delta^{n^2-k-2}_{-1}=\begin{cases}\frac{\pi i}{2^k}\ \ \text{if}\ \exists n:n^2=k+1\\0\ \ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$